# Default where clause, record viewing restriction

Tags: atk4

In a lot of applications users are allowed to see only certain records in a table, based on different things, such as statuses, roles, workflows...
Is there a way to specify at the model level a where clause that will always be applied anywhere the model is used. Or what would be a best practice using atk?

So for example you do a project management application. You want a user to see only the projects that are assigned to him or her, and everywhere, when logging time, creating defects, etc... he/she can see only those projects.

Comment: http://agiletoolkit.org/doc/modeltable/condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on how you want to design your application. The constraint are imposed by using  `addCondition` or `setMasterField` so if you put those constraint in model init you obtain what you want. You can design a base model that access all (for admin purposes) and use in the frontend application one or more child classes with the constraints in init. This is the usual way to be sure that a model is restricted to a certain part of the data.

Comment: The addCondition in the init function works really great. Is what I need. Thank you.

Comment: This works well, but when you add a filter on a grid, the where clause generated by the filter is appended using OR and then makes the filter defined using addCondition useless...